# browserslist: Versions of a specific browser released since a date

Tags: browser, cross-browser, babel-preset-env

Our policy is to support the Desktop versions of Firefox, Chrome and Edge that were stable in the last year.

Example: Today is 2022-01-12, so we support the releases of Chrome since 2022-01-11 and the release that was stable back then: 78 (2020-11-17), 88 (2021-01-19), 89 (2021-03-02), ..., 97 (2022-01-04)

My first try was: `Chrome since 2021-03` which resulted in this error: `Unknown browser query 'Chrome since 2021-03'. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.`

Following the grammar I tried: `Firefox and since 2021-03` but received: `Specify versions in Browserslist query for browser Firefox`

Since there is nothing like `all Firefox versions` I came up with: `last 99 Chrome versions and since 2021-01-12`

Although this works, I feel there must be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the syntax you usually use is `since YYYY-MM/-DD and browser_x > 0` so for chrome you could write `since 2021-01-12 and chrome > 0`.